# If particular id in SP no action required

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have particular id column in master table, while executing, there where no action required.

I mean nothing to change, if hits one particular id, How I can handle ?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Do you mean the primary key ?